# What is $dy/dy$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Say you have the following function:
$$y=x^2+x$$
Then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x+1$$
However, what if you wanted to find $dy/dy$? I differentiated both sides of the original equation with respect to $y$, getting
$$\frac{d}{dy}[y]=\frac{d}{dy}[x^2+x]$$
Now, I’ve always thought that $dy/dy=1$. After all, the derivative of a variable alone with respect to that variable is 1. However, if I apply the differentiation to the RHS, I’ll find that either of the terms are affected by the differentiation. Thus, 
$$\frac{dy}{dy}=x^2+x$$
The RHS here is the original $y$, so
$$\frac{dy}{dy}=y$$
This does not suggest that $dy/dy=1$. Obviously I’m making a mistake somewhere in my reasoning above. Can someone point out where I went wrong? $dy/dy=1$, correct? It does not equal $y$?

Comment: You cannot say that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d y}(x^2+x)=x^2+x$. Since $x^2+x=y$, $x$ depends on $y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not applied differentiation to the right hand side in the correct manner.

When you take the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, you must think of $x$ as the independent variable and $y$ as the dependent variable.

On the other hand, when you reverse the roles and take the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$, then you must think of $y$ as the independent variable and $x$ as the dependent variable. And when you do that then, by applying the chain rule, you get
$$\frac{d}{dy}[x^2 + x] = 2x \frac{dx}{dy} + \frac{dx}{dy}
$$

Comment: Sorry for reviving this, but how does this work if y is a constant, for example, y = 10. dy/dy = d(10)/dy. So 1= 0? that doesn't make sense

Comment: All of this presupposes that $y=f(x)$ is a one-to-one function, at least on part of its domain, in order that the inverse function $x=f^{-1}(y)$ exists. If $y=f(x)$ is not one-to-one then the question (and my answer) are nonsense. So for this problem where $y=x^2+x$, you would need to restrict the domain to make it one-to-one before any of this would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is simply in understanding the notation you are using, if $y = x^2 + x$ then $\frac{d}{dy} = \frac{d}{d(x^2 + x)}$, so the LHS is $\frac{dy}{dy} = 1$ and the right hand side is $\frac{d}{dy}(x^2 + x) = \frac{d}{d(x^2 + x)}(x^2 + x) = 1$ so both sides agree.

The point is that in ignoring the relationship between $x$ and $y$ you are not differentiating correctly. Also note that if we really didn't have a link between $x$ and  $y$ then $\frac{d}{dy}(x^2 + x)$ would be equal to zero not 1.